# Is there a way to use CellPrint on dataset objects?

Tags: dataset, cells, printing

I am trying to assign a cell tag onto my cell with contents in the form of a dataset. However, I am receiving the following error:

> The wrong number of arguments (12) was given to a box ("BoxData") in the BoxForm of the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

Any way to access the number of arguments of `BoxData` or find another workaround to this problem?

Comment: This title is, I think, incomplete as you can in fact print `Dataset` objects: `CellPrint[Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Dataset[<|1 -> 2|>]]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
data=Dataset[{<|"x"->1,"y"->-2|>,<|"x"->-3,"y"->4|>}];

CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[data, "Output", CellTags->"FOO"]
```

perhaps?

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't realize that there are different Cell options. Thank you so much.